# Generate more points between two longitude-lattitude points

Tags: python, python-3.x, latitude-longitude

In a 2D plane, given two points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`, it is straight forward to generate `N` equally spaced points along the straight line between the two points. This also applies for 3D plane.

However, I'm trying to work out how would you do so for geo-coordinated points. To illustrate my point further, say you have point A with `(latA, lonA)` that represents the lattitude and longitude of its, and another point B with `(latB, lonB)`. How would you generate `N` points between A and B? Is there a straightforward library in `python` that could achieve this?

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221843/how-to-interpolate-a-lat-long-point-between-two-others-at-a-given-distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this directly with numpy. The idea is to use the standard interpolation formula for 3D space, like `A + d * (B - A)`. Points computed like this lie on the chord between A and B but can be projected back to the sphere.

In order to have a uniform distribution over angles, we need the mapping from angles to distances on the chord, like in the figure here

[image: Geometry]

This shows chord locations for uniformly spaced angles and was generated with the code below to check correctness, since all the angles and trigonometric functions are easy to mess up.

```
def embed_latlon(lat, lon):
    """lat, lon -> 3d point"""
    lat_, lon_ = np.deg2rad(lat), np.deg2rad(lon)
    r = np.cos(lat_)
    return np.array([
        r * np.cos(lon_),
        r * np.sin(lon_),
        np.sin(lat_)
    ]).T

def project_latlon(x):
    """3d point -> (lat, lon)"""
    return (
        np.rad2deg(np.arcsin(x[:, 2])),
        np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(x[:, 1], x[:, 0]))
    )

def _great_circle_linspace_3d(x, y, n):
    """interpolate two points on the unit sphere"""
    # angle from scalar product
    alpha = np.arccos(x.dot(y))
    # angle relative to mid point
    beta = alpha * np.linspace(-.5, .5, n)
    # distance of interpolated point to center of sphere
    r = np.cos(.5 * alpha) / np.cos(beta)
    # distance to mid line
    m = r * np.sin(beta)
    # interpolation on chord
    chord = 2. * np.sin(.5 * alpha) 
    d = (m + np.sin(.5 * alpha)) / chord

    points = x[None, :] + (y - x)[None, :] * d[:, None]
    return points / np.sqrt(np.sum(points**2, axis=1, keepdims=True))

def great_circle_linspace(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, n):
    """interpolate two points on the unit sphere"""
    x = embed_latlon(lat1, lon1)
    y = embed_latlon(lat2, lon2)
    return project_latlon(_great_circle_linspace_3d(x, y, n))

# example on equator
A = 0, 0.
B = 0., 30.

great_circle_linspace(*A, *B, n=5)
(array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([ 0. ,  7.5, 15. , 22.5, 30. ]))
```